# Powershell adding a list of string to an object

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a solution to add a list a strings to an XML object

This is from the documentation of the web service that I need to call:

> fileNames: List of String To specify more than one file name multiple
>   fileNames parameters must be  used as shown below:
>
> `<!--1 or more repetitions:--> 
>   <xsd1:fileNames>test1.txt</xsd1:fileNames> 
>   <xsd1:fileNames>test2.txt</xsd1:fileNames>`

Adding a second property with the same name is not allowed

```
$soap.Envelope.Body.sampleobject | Add-Member -MemberType Property -Name fileNamesList -Value $fileNames[0]
#This works fine

$soap.Envelope.Body.sampleobject | Add-Member -MemberType Property -Name fileNamesList -Value $fileNames[1]
#This fails with error message "Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "fileNamesList" because a member with that name already exists.  "
```

If possible I want to avoid to deal with the SOAP object as a string and insert strings.

Is there an elegant way to manage this with powershell?

UPDATE
Some more code

```
$soap = [xml]@'
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <sampleObject>
         <Name>MySampleObject</Name>
      </sampleObject>
   </Body>
   </Envelope>
'@

[string[]]$filenames='filea.txt','fileb.txt'

$soap.Envelope.Body.sampleObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name fileNames -Value $fileNames

$soap.envelope.body.sampleObject | fl   #1
write-host "`r`n" $soap.OuterXml        #2
```

Outputs:

#1: object contains the filenames

```
fileNames : {filea.txt, fileb.txt}
Name      : MySampleObject
```

#2: filenames are missing when sent to xml Webservice

```
<Envelope><Body><sampleObject><Name>MySampleObject</Name></sampleObject></Body></Envelope>
```

Comment: Why not just do `Add-Member -Value $fileNames` once?

Comment: this doesn't work. I will update my question.

Comment: `Add-Member -Value @($fileNames |%{"$_"})` then

Comment: Sorry, still not woking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Add-Member` to modify an XML document.

Instead, create a new node and append it to `sampleObject` with the `AppendChild()` method:

```
$soap = [xml]@'
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <sampleObject>
         <Name>MySampleObject</Name>
      </sampleObject>
   </Body>
   </Envelope>
'@

$filenames='filea.txt','fileb.txt'

foreach($filename in $filenames)
{
    $NewNode = $soap.CreateElement('filenames')
    $NewNode.InnerText = $filename
    [void]$soap.Envelope.Body.sampleObject.AppendChild($NewNode)
}
```

The XML Document now contains your `filenames` nodes:

```
PS C:\> $soap.OuterXml
<Envelope><Body><sampleObject><Name>MySampleObject</Name><filenames>filea.txt</filenames><filenames>fileb.txt</filenames></sampleObject></Body></Envelope>
```